# How to set state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am having `Button` in my header, that has function onClick to open the `Drawer`. Right now `Header` component is a **child** component of `index.jsx`

**This is the structure:**

```
// index.jsx -> page holds all the functions above, Header is component

         <Header
                countCartItems={cartItems.length}
                cartItems={cartItems}
                onAdd={onAdd}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
            />
```

**Header.jsx**

```
const Header = (props) => { 
........
<button onClick={() => props.setCartOpen(true)}>
        <Badge badgeContent={props.countCartItems} />
                          
</button>
........
}
```

Code above works perfectly fine, **BUT** only when I am on index.page

I need `Header` component to also import on other pages, but in that case, when I want to click on my Button and open the cart I am getting error of:

**TypeError: props.setCartOpen is not a function**

I tried to pass the props again, but it does not work, since all the functions are hold in `index.jsx`.

If I put `Header` into `App.js`, the problem is the same. Is there any solution for this? Or do I have to move everything into `App.js`? There must be a way how to share the props between.

**Passing Header in another page:**

```
const NewPage = ({setCartOpen}) => { 
.......
   <Header setCartOpen={setCartOpen} />
.......
}
```

The thing is, the new page is NOT a child of index page, so I don't know how to pass it properly.

**Router.js**

```
 <Route path={baseRouteUrl + '/new-page'}
        component={(props) => <NewPage />}
 ></Route>
```

Comment: "Or do I have to move everything into App.js ?" Yes , certainly. @TechGirl

Comment: probably you missed the setCartOpen function to pass into the header from other page where you getting the error, please double check that, if not, can you please share how you calling the header in the page where you getting the error.

Comment: I edited the post @VijayKumawat, you can see my attempt.

Comment: you have to change the new page to `const NewPage = ({setCartOpen}) => { ` .

Comment: I did. Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: where you calling NewPage? can you share that too?

Comment: Yes, I updated again :) @VijayKumawat

Comment: You are not sending the 'setCartOpen' in newPage's props. That's why it's giving error of not a function

Comment: But how should I set it up @VijayKumawat ? If I set it up in the imported NewPage component, it does not know what setCartOpen should do.

Comment: The best way in this situation is to use context. Your cartOpen flag can be stored in app context and then can be accessed throughout the app

Answer (score 0):

you can use React.Context and this context object is available through the entire componet tree

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
const ValueContext = createContext(); // React Context saves you from prop drilling

function Child() {
 return (
   <div>
     <ValueContext>
       {(value) => {
                   // you can also pass setValue() and is passed along the component tree
         return <p>{value.value}</p>;
       }}
     </ValueContext>
   </div>
 );
}

function App() {
 const [value, setValue] = useState("hello world");

 return (
   <ValueContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
     <div>
       <Child />
     </div>
   </ValueContext.Provider>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, can you be more specific and give example connected to my post @Juno ? Did not use `context` before.

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to persist and share a state between all of your components you should use the ContextAPI or react-redux because you should imagine props propagating as starting from the top of a tree at a node and passing down to children of that node.
as always the React docs are a great resource if you never used the ContextAPI before https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html .
Otherwise What I would suggest is if you need to set the `cartOpen` property externally you could do that using the useState hook within the other page and then passing that state variable as a prop to `<Header/>` this way you would only give true or false to `<Header/>` and then do what you have to do with it.

Comment: Thank you @SidBarrack, I will try to follow the way with React Context, hopefully I'll be successful.

Comment: awesome! and if it works don't forget to mark the answer as the correct answer to help others who'll encounter the same issue.